# Ошибка в class-based django

Tags: python, django

Помогите найти ошибку в классе. Как передать переменную quiz в контекст?

model

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100,default="")
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Question(models.Model):
question = models.TextField(max_length=200,default="")
option1 = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="")
option2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
option3 = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
option4 = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
option5 = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
answer = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz)

def __str__(self):
    return self.question

class Quize(models.Model):
author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
text = models.ForeignKey(Quiz)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

view

```
  class Ans(generic.ListView):
    model = Quiz
    template_name = 'test.html' 

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Quiz.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now())  

    def answerq(self):
        quiz = self.get_queryset()
        response = (Quiz, quiz_id)
        return response
```

Comment: Конечная цель какая? Что за переменная? почему Вы в модель, которая вообще то является классом передаете некую переменную?

Comment: Цель - передать quiz_id в шаблон. модель находится в models.py

Comment: Тогда и модель нужна. Обычно не так пишут view. :)

Comment: добавил медельку

Comment: Не совсем понятно, как Вы class завязали на view через urls.... Обычно это пишется несколько иначе... Функция, которая в template передает данные из queryset, например... У Вас же как то интересно всё. Не понятно, что Вы хотите вывести в конечном итоге.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич см. предыдущий его вопрос, тут каша в голове, с которой я до сих пор не придумал что делать

Comment: с предыдущим вопросом я уже разобрался

Comment: @andreymal а я тут уже стал представлять себе сложнейшие конструкции по типу вызова методов класса, которые выполняют какие то очень интересные задачи вывода в некие очень красивые паттерны в template :))

Answer (score 0):

У какого то родительского класса ListView есть аттрибут context_object_name

То есть дал ему строку 'ans_list' , шаблон должен выглядить так {% for object.id in ans_list %}

Comment: Если я правильно понял суть вопроса. Потому что сам не давно трэйсил подобную проблему. Не плохо было бы скрин браузера с Ошибкой скинуть